# My delegate is nil when trying to remove child from parent IOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I have a child view which takes over the entire parent view. I want the child to be removed from the parent by call a method from the parent using a protocol but my delegate is nil every time. I add my sample work below if you need more information just let me know

```
protocol childDelegate: class {
           func removeFromParent()
        }
        class ChildAction: UITableViewController {
           @IBAction func btnRemove(_sender: Any){
              if(delegate != nil){
               self.delegate?.removeFromParent()
            }
          }  
        }
        class ParentClass: UIViewController:childDelegate {

         var delegate:childDelegate?
         private ChildActionView:ChildAction{
             let storyboard = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
             let viewC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildAction") as! ChildAction
              self.delegate = viewC as? childDelegate
              self.addChildViewController(viewC)
              return viewC

         }
        @IBAction func btnAddChild(_sender: Any){
              addChild(child:ChildActionView)
            }

        func addChild(child: UIViewController){
            self.addChildViewController(child)
            view.addSubview(child.view)
            child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        }

          func removeFromParent(){
              //remove from parent 

          }
        }
```

[Child view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5rS2.png)
[parent view controller image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axHVf.png)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I've added two image under the code snippet

Comment: Delete all code images. Copy all code

Comment: @Honey you nailed it

Answer (score 1):

No where in your code did you set the `delegate` variable of your `ChildAction` instance (your `childVC`). You set `parent's delegate` to child but that is meaningless in your code. You need to set `child's delegate` to parent. Currently child do not have any reference of its parent, so naturally its delegate is `nil`. Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you read an article or tutorial or two about the  Delegate pattern. Things will be much easier if you have a basic understanding of how it is *supposed* to work.

Compare this code to what you posted. See if it makes sense.

```
protocol childDelegate: class {
    func removeFromParent()
}

class ChildAction: UIViewController {

    // this class gets the delegate, because it wants to "call back" to a delegated function
    var delegate:childDelegate?

    @IBAction func btnRemove(_sender: Any){
        // IF delegate has been assigned, call its function
        delegate?.removeFromParent()
    }
}

class ParentClass: UIViewController, childDelegate {

    // bad naming... would be much clearer if it was "childActionViewController" or "childActionVC"
    private let ChildActionView: ChildAction = {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildAction") as! ChildAction
        return viewC

    }()

    @IBAction func btnAddChild(_sender: Any){
        // add the child view controller
        self.addChildViewController(ChildActionView)
        // set its delegate to self
        ChildActionView.delegate = self
        // add its view to the hierarchy
        view.addSubview(ChildActionView.view)
        // finish the process
        ChildActionView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }

    func removeFromParent() {
        //remove from parent
        print("removeFromParent() called...")
    }

}
```

Comment: You are correct I see my mistake I will review some tutorial to get a better understanding of Delegate pattern